# Global State / Configuration Models In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, global-variables

I have a set of configuration variables (not environment specific) that need to be wrapped in a class that exposes them to the rest of the application. If all I wanted to expose was the values, I could load them via a YAML file / expose on the Rails config object, however I want the class to offer a simple API that combines / manipulates these pieces of data. This data will never change after initialisation, but needs to be used in numerous places. Storing it in the database seems like unnecessary complexity.

I initially experimented with storing state on a class and accessing it via class methods: `Example.getter`, but this is problematic in development due to class reloading blowing away the state. The same is true for Singletons.

Another alternative is storing them on an instance of a class, but where should that instance live? I could add it to the Rails config object and access it there, but using the config object as some kind of registry doesn't feel right: `Rails.application.config.example.getter` and is very verbose.

How should I store this kinds of configuration so it is easy to access from within the application?